# How to fix Error: "module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'" when calling pip

Tags: python, pip

On my WSL im getting the error `AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'` whenever I try to use pip e.g. `pip list`, `python3 -m pip`, etc.

Is there a way to reinstall pip or uninstall packages without using pip? I tried following the solutions in related Questions but none of them work because they either use pip or the problem persists after.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+module+lib+has+no+attribute+X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428181/module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check/1433089#1433089).
you have to remove the line:

> CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK

from this file:

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py

and then you can use `pip` again:

```bash
$ pip uninstall cryptography
$ pip install --upgrade cryptography==36.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me on my Debian-on-ChromeOS

Comment: Fixed my issue on Ubuntu WSL2 when running pip

Comment: This worked for me as well, i wish i knew why!

Comment: It worked for me too trying to run *awslocal* execpt it was the above line and:
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY'
that needed to be commented out.